# remove characters from column names

Tags: r, tidyverse

I try to remove in R, some characters unwanted from my column names (numbers, . and space)
I have column names as follows

My data is tibble

`tibble [33 x 38] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ year                                             : chr [1:33] "1988" "1989" "1990" "1991" ...
 $ VALOR  AGREGADO  BRUTO (a  precios  básicos)     : num [1:33] 9906283 11624212 14163419 17400488 19785184 ...
 $ 1. PRODUCTOS AGRÍCOLAS NO INDUSTRIALES           : num [1:33] 831291 911372 1112167 1434213 1532067 ...
 $ 2. PRODUCTOS AGRÍCOLAS INDUSTRIALES              : num [1:33] 143426 214369 231168 341144 282777 ...
 $ 3. COCA                                          : num [1:33] 118273 153689 195108 190264 199259 ...`

And I desired column names were.

`tibble [33 x 38] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ year                                             : chr [1:33] "1988" "1989" "1990" "1991" ...
 $ VALOR  AGREGADO  BRUTO (a  precios  básicos)     : num [1:33] 9906283 11624212 14163419 17400488 19785184 ...
 $ PRODUCTOS AGRÍCOLAS NO INDUSTRIALES           : num [1:33] 831291 911372 1112167 1434213 1532067 ...
 $ PRODUCTOS AGRÍCOLAS INDUSTRIALES              : num [1:33] 143426 214369 231168 341144 282777 ...
 $ COCA                                          : num [1:33] 118273 153689 195108 190264 199259 ...`

I want remove number and . from colnames

```
colnames(data) <- sub("\\1:4\.\\", "", colnames(data))
colnames(data)
```

Please somebody could help me?

Best!
Marcelo

Comment: `[1-4]` not `1:4` in regular expressions and the escaping \\ doesn't look right - have a read of https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/regex to get the syntax right.

Comment: `d %>%rename_with(~str_remove(.x, '\\d+\\.'))%>%janitor::clean_names()`

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what was wrong with the answers you got, but here's another try. Since you're showing a `data.frame` and want to rename the columns, you can use the `str_replace()` inside `dplyr::rename_with()`. Also, since your data has `38` columns, I'm guessing you may need to remove numbers other than just `1-4`. To accommodate that I opened the range to all numbers by including `[0-9]` and allowed either `1` or `2` digit numbers by indicating `{1,2}` after the numeral specification.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# took the column names you showed and added one with a higher number
d <- tibble(year = 1:5,
       "VALOR  AGREGADO  BRUTO (a  precios  básicos)" = 1:5,
       "1. PRODUCTOS AGRÍCOLAS NO INDUSTRIALES" = 1:5,
       "2. PRODUCTOS AGRÍCOLAS INDUSTRIALES" = 1:5,
       "3. COCA" = 1:5,
       "29. OTHER" = 1:5)

# rename_with takes a renaming function
d %>% 
  rename_with(~str_remove(.x, "[0-9]{1,2}. "))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#>    year `VALOR  AGREGADO  BRUTO ~` `PRODUCTOS AGR~` `PRODUCTOS AGR~`  COCA OTHER
#>   <int>                      <int>            <int>            <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1                          1                1                1     1     1
#> 2     2                          2                2                2     2     2
#> 3     3                          3                3                3     3     3
#> 4     4                          4                4                4     4     4
#> 5     5                          5                5                5     5     5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but not work like I want :)

Comment: Please explain in more detail how this output differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

We can use this pattern that reads, replace if it starts with one or more digit followed by a dot and a space.

```r
library(stringr)

data <- c("1. PRODUCTOS AGRÍCOLAS NO INDUSTRIALES",
"2. PRODUCTOS AGRÍCOLAS INDUSTRIALES",
"3. SILVICULTURA, CAZA Y PESCA",
"4. PRODUCTOS PECUARIOS") 
  
str_replace(data, '^\\d+\\. ', "")
#> [1] "PRODUCTOS AGRÍCOLAS NO INDUSTRIALES" "PRODUCTOS AGRÍCOLAS INDUSTRIALES"   
#> [3] "SILVICULTURA, CAZA Y PESCA"          "PRODUCTOS PECUARIOS"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but not work like I want :)